# Hosting my own site - pros/cons?

Tags: domain, hosting

I am very interested in creating my own professional website. It won't be used for any business purposes, but will simply be a lightweight site that will serve my resume/CV, etc., and also a blog.

Now, as I understand from the research I have done, Wordpress itself is simply a content-manager, which enables be to easily build webpages with a plethora of plugins at my disposal. What you actually have to pay for is hosting and a domain name.

Is there anything to be said against hosting my own website? I'd like to get an Apache server up and running on my Raspberry Pi3, install wordpress, and simply run it from my home. This should only be a few dollars a year for a domain name, and that's it.

Is there anything to be said against this? Seems like a reasonable choice that will save money. As I said, the site will be lightweight - I will have a 64gb sd in my pi as the drive, and it has 1gb ram, so it may not be super quick with a wordpress installation but I think that's probably alright.

My plan would be something like this;

- Configure Pi and install apache
- install wordpress
- do whatever port forwarding needs to be done
- buy domain name, $12/year from Google
- find a solution to the dynamic IP problem... perhaps just use no-ip and point my domain there?

And I think that's it, no? Of course I would also have some kind of automatic cloud backup running, maybe just to a google drive or something.

Assuming the technical know-how isn't an issue, why would someone *not* do this? Any advice?

Comment: If you want just a lightweight site,  you could use github pages,  which lets you host amazing static websites for free. Check out portfolio I created within minutes using github pages https://digvijayad.github.io .  It uses jekyll and markdown. You can also redirect it to your own domain. Check out some of the free jekyll themes here http://jekyllthemes.org.

Comment: No reason not to. If you were talking about a business site selling things, or anything that would grow hugely popular, you might run into issues trying to serve from your own internet connection. ISPs tend to throttle you when you consume too much bandwidth. But assuming you're just talking low visits, your Raspberry Pi is a great place to start.

Comment: I want to say "go for it", but on the other hand, when you have a VPS that gets hacked, it isn't really a big problem aside from your website being down. If you have somebody on your RPi in your home network doing nasty things, that might be another story.

Comment: @Digvijayad So how did you actually build that? Is there some kind of gui design environment? You install wordpress on it? It looks like it is some kind of applied theme. Also, this is what I don't understand... why are people with sites like yours paying for hosting when there are options like this?

Comment: @janh what is VPS?

Comment: No wordpress, as I mentioned I used github pages which hosts the site for free, I didn't pay a dime to host that site. Check out some of these links to get a better understanding of github pages: https://pages.github.com. This is theme I used https://github.com/digvijayad/freelancer-theme. The setup information is in the readme

Comment: @Digvijayad I understand that you host on github, but wordpress is a content-manager, not a hosting service. So github pages isn't really an alternative to wordpress, right? Is Jekyll the wordpress alternative in this setup?

Comment: @jphollowed: Virtual Private Server. Basically a Virtual Machine on a server in a datacenter. They are usually very cheap (I've seen offers as low as $1/month) and it's not unusual that they come with a domain. They will be a bit quicker than your RPi, and have a much stronger connection.

Comment: Github pages can be used to host static sites with simple html,  css,  and js. You cannot use any Server side language on it. Jekyll on the other hand is a static site generator which converts markdown text to static html. https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-as-a-static-site-generator-with-github-pages/. Unfortunately there is no cms involved in this. You can however maintain good looking lightweight sites and blogs using the themes and markdown. These themes provide a placeholder text which you just replace with your own info. Check out the `read me` of link in my previous comment

Comment: @Digvijayad I've looked into this some more - GitHub pages looks absurdly easy (considering I am very familiar with git). I also see that you can indeed use Wordpress on it, though I don't yet fully understand exactly what wordpress offers and if that would be necessary or not

Comment: If you do use wordpress you will need to convert your website to static html pages. Which you can then host on your github. I think there is a plugin in WordPress which does that. Read this for pro-cons http://perfectionkills.com/moving-from-wordpress-to-github-pages/

Answer (score 0):

I have a 'vanity' domain name and a web site to go with it. It's hosted by a big-time hosting place. It's a static HTML/PHP page, but I've also done 'vanity' sites by using a simple WordPress theme.

Although you can host on your own server at your house, there are security risks involved, along with maintenance. First, do you have a dedicated IP address with your ISP (which will cost extra, although there is some geeky stuff you can add to do that)? If not, you'll need to do additional tricks to 'point' your domain to your server. And there are some internal firewall/port forwarding you will have to do locally, and protection for other devices/users on your internal network. A lot of security risk if you don't do it right.

This is all 'fun' for geeky-types, and might be worth the effort. But I think the risks and work is a big consideration for self-hosting. You can purchase a domain name (which you will need anyhow) and cheap hosting for a couple $ a month. And that lets the hosting place worry about all the security and updates. You just worry about the content.

Some hosting plans will allow you to have multiple domain names on your hosting plan (I've got 20-40 domains on mine, but I've upgraded the hosting plan).

Even though I'm a geek, I'd rather the hosting place both with that stuff. I'll geek on the content.